# How to have global store to share with other store in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have for example 2 store files in my nuxt project: store/users, store/posts

in my users i have :

```js
    export const state = () => ({
      name: null,
      mail: null
    })
    
    export const mutations = {
      edit(state, data) {
        state.name = data.name,
        state.mail = data.mail
      },
    }
```

and in my posts:

```js
    export const state = () => ({
          title: null,
          content: null
        })
    
    export const mutations = {
      edit(state, data) {
        state.title = data.title,
        state.content = data.content
      },
    }
```

so that i want is to have another store who take global value like

```js
    export const state = () => ({
       list: [],
    })

    export const mutations = {
      add(state, data) {
        state.list.push(data)
      },
    }
```

so in the end i want to use this last store as if my store look like this

users store

```js
    export const state = () => ({
      name: null,
      mail: null,
      list: []
    })
    
    export const mutations = {
      edit(state, data) {
        state.name = data.name,
        state.mail = data.mail
      },
      add(state, data) {
        state.list.push(data)
      },
    }
```

posts store

```js
    export const state = () => ({
      title: null,
      content: null,
      list: []
    })
    
    export const mutations = {
      edit(state, data) {
        state.title = data.title,
        state.content = data.content
      },
      add(state, data) {
        state.list.push(data)
      },
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to acomplish? Why would you want to do that kind of "merge" between stores?

Comment: Instead of copy the same code for all store, i want to have one store who can be used by all other store as if its their own store parameter, so i can save time and code space :)

Comment: Sorry, not really;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a more generic namespaced module, you can use global Vuex actions: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#dispatch

This paired with `rootState` https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mutations

Would be enough to make something generic. I've achieved it this way with some dynamic interpolation and conditional. Beware of not making it too complex tho, 100% DRY is not always the best. Sometimes some repetition can be totally fine!

Comment: i want this way cause all my module store can all have much code that the same